# Joining two tables twice with different rows selected each time

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I have to join wp_posts with wp_postsmeta twice to get the rows. First with the `post_type=product` and next with the `post_type=attachment`.

wp_posts:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ post_type  ║ guid                                                ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 48 ║ product    ║ http://example.com/xyz                              ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

wp_postsmeta

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ meta_id ║ post_id ║ meta_key      ║ meta_value║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 200     ║ 48      ║ _price        ║ 100       ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Query:

Next, I also want to join `wp_posts` with `wp_postsmeta` again with `post_type = attachment` and `meta_key =_thumbnail`

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ post_type  ║ guid                                                ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 150║ attachment ║ http://example.com/xyz.png                          ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

wp_postsmeta:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ meta_id ║ post_id ║ meta_key      ║ meta_value║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 200     ║ 48      ║ _thumbnail    ║ 150       ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Then I have use the meta_value of the result and join that again with wp_posts (primary key wp_posts.id = wp_postsmeta.meta_value) so I get the featured images of product from them.

Below is my complete query

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.guid, p3.guid
FROM wp_posts p1 
     JOIN wp_postmeta p2
     ON p1.ID = p2.post_id AND
        p2.meta_key = '_price' AND
        p1.post_type = 'product' AND
        p1.post_status = 'publish' 
     JOIN wp_posts p3
     ON p3.ID = p2.post_id AND 
        p2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
     JOIN wp_postmeta p4
     ON p4.post_id = p3.ID AND
        p3.post_type = 'attachment';
```

The above query returns empty result (it shouldn't be empty but return the table as below)

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ post_type  ║ guid                    ║  guid                      ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ 48 ║ product    ║ http://example.com/xyz  ║ http://example.com/xyz.png ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: You are joining `p3` on `p2` with `p2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'` but you have before filtered `p2` with `p2.meta_key = '_price'` then you cannot get results.

Comment: @Troopers: How to solve this?

Comment: @FahadUddin Apart from what @Troopers mentioned, you are joining both `p1.ID = p2.post_id` and `p3.ID = p2.post_id`. It means that records from both p1 and p3 need to have same ID, however in the example you provided first record has ID = 48 and second has ID = 150. There is no connection between these two records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT posts.post_title,posts.ID, posts.post_name, (SELECT guid from wp_posts AS thumbnailpost INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON (`wp_postmeta`.meta_value = thumbnailpost.ID) where `wp_postmeta`.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' AND `wp_postmeta`.post_id = 2856) AS thumbnail FROM `wp_posts` AS posts where posts.post_type = 'product' and posts.post_status='publish' group by posts.ID limit 100
```

**Updated**

Do you want like this?

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.guid,
(select p.guid from wp_posts as p where p2.meta_value=p.ID and post_type='attachment') img
FROM wp_posts p1 
     JOIN wp_postmeta p2
     ON p1.ID = p2.post_id AND       
        p1.post_type = 'product' AND
        p1.post_status = 'publish' AND
         p2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
     JOIN wp_posts p3
     ON p3.ID = p2.post_id
```

Comment: This gets the other results but the last column in  null

Comment: You have to use sub query